# SVG Arc command with six parameters

Tags: parsing, svg

I found this SVG, which I am trying to parse with my own SVG parser: https://jsfiddle.net/nmapf2do/

There is the Arc command with only six parameters instead of seven:

```
a  4.12  4.12  0  0   14.13  0
```

What does it mean? How should it be interpreted? It seems like browsers accept it, but I can not find anything about it in the [SVG specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Comment: I suppose it's `a  4.12  4.12  0  0   1 4.13  0` instead of  `a  4.12  4.12  0  0   14.13  0`. Strangely enough if you use  `a  4.12  4.12  0  0   4.13  0` you can see the error which means that the browser can handle the lack of space between 1 and 4

Comment: @enxaneta Exactly. I see you can even have "five numbers" in a valid Arc command: `a  4.12  4.12  0  114.13  0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc does have 7 parameters i.e. it's really

```
a  4.12  4.12  0  0 1 4.13  0
```

Because the sweep flag can only be 0 or 1 so once we've read a character we move on to reading the next value. No separator is required [per the BNF](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataBNF).

> elliptical-arc-argument:
>       nonnegative-number comma-wsp? nonnegative-number comma-wsp?
>             number comma-wsp flag comma-wsp? **flag** comma-wsp? coordinate-pair

> flag:
>       "0" | "1"

Comment: OMG, that just blew my mind! I would never thought we should parse it like this.